# How to insert a column value to only first thousand rows

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table called GSH where values already exists.

Have added a new column named 'GS' in the table 'GSH'.I have to add values to the newly added column only for the first thousand rows selected from GSH table.

How to write the SQL query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what defines  'the first thousand rows'?

Comment: Database used : Sql ...Just want to select the first thousand rows say by using rownum condition.

Comment: @Padmaja , SQL is a Query language and that name is being used across all DBMS. Hence Pls mention which DBMS you are using such as Oracle , MySQL , MSSQL etc.,

Comment: Also, please note that [database tables are unsorted by nature](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/), so there is no "first x rows" unless you can specify a column to sort by.

Comment: DBMS used is Oracle...And only 1000 rows..No condition to be applied on any column...eg : select * from ghs where rownum<=1000..only for these 1000 rows I want to insert value for the newly added column.

Comment: You want an UPDATE not an insert

Comment: Do you have an id column? Or anything else that is specific for each row?

Comment: This isn't "first 1000 rows", it's "arbitrary 1000 rows".

Comment: No id column present in the table..I have time column..I can modify my question...Want to add values to the newly added column for that particular day..

Answer (score 1):

If I followed you correctly, you want to add data in the column for random 1000 rows. (Update value of the newly column)

```
Update GSH
SET GS = 1 -- replace 1 with value that you want to fill it with
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solved your problem so that this question is marked as resolved

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below (assuming you want to pick any 100 rows)

```
update GSH 
set GS = 'your values logic'
where rowid in (
select rowid 
from GSH
where rownum < 101);
```

This is the script I used to recreate your scenario

```
drop table temp;

create table temp (temp1 varchar2(100));

begin 
for rec in 1..500
loop
insert into temp values('s');
end loop;
commit;

end;
/


alter table temp add  temp2 varchar2(200);

update temp 
set temp2 = 'your values logic'
where rowid in (
select rowid 
from temp
where rownum < 101);
```